# Which RAID caching policy to use?

Tags: raid

I'm in the process of setting up a server.  Dell PE R510, 6 450GB HD.  It came with all drives RAID 5'd, I'm wanting to wipe the configuration and set 0 and 1 as RAID 1, then 2-5 as RAID 5.  When I go to setup RAID 1, it's asking me about which Caching Policy to use - Read/Write, Write only, Read only, and none.  I'm not sure which to pick here...suggestions?  This server will be used for Exchange 2010 and the RAID 1 drives will be used for the OS and Logs, and the server will be on a battery backup.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: does your raid card have a battery backup? If not read only; If so your call on read only or read/write

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The RAID write cache policy should be set depending on the disk I/O load. You must make sure that you have a battery on the RAID controller and that the battery is functional.

The cache policy settings can be changed at any time from Dell OMSA.

I suggest to start with write caching disabled and only if you have problems with the I/O to change the write cache policy.

I would use RAID10 only instead of splitting that stuff in a RADI5 and RAID1 volumes.

Comment: Why would you start with write cache disabled?

Comment: Batteries fail. Power failures happen. Why introduce another hazard when I do not need it? I already have the FS cache inside the OS. Imagine having 100 servers, if I increase the chances for them to fail with only 1% this means that I have high chances for one to fail when I will have the next power failure.

Comment: Thanks, it's good to know I can change it after the fact!